# Spring Data Paging over combined Result of several Queries

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-jpa

We are using Spring Boot 2 with Spring Data and its PagingAndSortingRepository feature. This works well for single queries, but in one case we have to make three different queries and implement pagination for the combined result.

What is the best way to do it?

Here's what I have tried:

1) Write a UNION or JOIN query of sorts that already returns the combined result as a Page or Slice. However, this query takes almost 10 times as long as shooting three seperate queries and do the aggregation in Java. We are talking complex computations here (PostGIS backend).

2) Manually construct the pages/slices by using the existing SliceImpl or PageImpl classes. This works fine for the initial request, but fails on the second request, when the user says something like: give me page 1 (page size == 10 items). The first page (page 0) may have had 4 items from the first query and 6 of 12 total items from the second query. Asking for page 1 gives me then 0 results from the first query and 2 (instead of 6) from the second, while filling up the rest from the third query. So clearly, this cannot work from a logical point of view.

Any other ideas?

Edit: we are planning to add Hibernate Search and Caching, which might solve this problem externally by making option 1) fast enough. My question was meant to ask for an "internal" solution, i. e. some code I can write today, until we have the external solution in place.

Answer (score 0):

As you have described in point 2, unless you do always left join between queries, no one can guarantee you that what you have retrieved with the first query part is sufficient to generate a page of 10 valid element.

Implement a logic that find element until the page is complete it's more expensive than the single query for sure... specially when you have to increment pages more and more.

I think you have to combine all your queries in a single query.

A solution in this case could be to create a materialized view on your database and apply simpler filters.

To have a cache framework can help too.